# How to use git sparse-checkout with multiple matching patterns

Tags: git, glob, sparse-checkout, git-sparse-checkout

I'm using `git sparse-checkout` to have only the files I'm interested in on disk. I'm unable to figure out how to match multiple patterns.

```
git sparse-checkout set --no-cone "**/*.tf"
```

Checkout all `.tf` files

```
git sparse-checkout set --no-cone "**/*.tf.json"
```

Checkout all `.tf.json` files

How can I checkout all files that fit both patterns at once?  I've tried

```
git sparse-checkout set --no-cone "**/*.tf **/*.tf.json"
git sparse-checkout set --no-cone "**/*.tf,**/*.tf.json"
git sparse-checkout set --no-cone "**/*.tf\n**/*.tf.json"
```

But none of these options match either pattern

Answer (score 1):

I had misread the docs. Each pattern is a new argument, so the following works

```
git sparse-checkout set --no-cone "**/*.tf" "**/*.tf.json"
```

From the [docs on `set`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-sparse-checkout/2.26.0#_commands):

> Write a set of patterns to the sparse-checkout file, as given as a list of arguments following the set subcommand.